# Equations and primes

Tags: number-theory

Lets have the equation $x^3=2y^2+z^2$, where all numbers positive integers. What are the necessary conditions for $x$, and $x-1$ to be prime numbers?

Answer (score 5):

If you want $x$ and $x-1$ to both be prime, the only solution is $x=3$  Then we have $27=2y^2+z^2$.  We must have $z$ odd so the right side is odd.  There aren't many choices to try, and $y=z=3$ solves the equation, as does $y=1, z=5$.

Comment: Millican.What I asked is $x$ or $x-1$ to be prime

Comment: It looks like "and" to me.  The original had $x-1$ in square brackets, but the and was there.

Comment: Millican. These two equations derive from above. 11^3=33^2+11^2+11^2, 6^3=12^2+6^2+6^2

Comment: I'm not sure what primes have to do with it, especially $x-1$. Given one solution, you can multiply $x$ by $n^2$ and $y,z$ by $n^3$to get another.

Comment: Your solutions are correct.  By the process I indicated, we get $12^3=2\cdot 24^2+24^2$ which shows why I think $x-1$ being prime is not interesting.  Having $x$ prime shows a solution is not derived from another in this way.  I would claim your $6^3=12^2+2\cdot 6^2$ is a primitive solution.  It could come from $x=y=z=3$ by $x \to 2x, z \to 2y, y \to 4z$ but that only works if $y=z$